# Looking for a small footprint perl implementation for Windows 10

Tags: perl, windows-10, diskspace

I have a Windows 10 system with limited storage space - and am looking for an implementation of perl that will take up as little space on the disk as possible.

I've been using Strawberry Perl - which uses about 500 MB.

My perl needs are minimal, but I may need to install a couple of cpan modules.

I found a "Tiny Perl" on SourceForge - but it hasn't been touched in *years* - so I'm reluctant to even try it.

Can anyone recommend a good solution here?

Thanks.

Comment: That is Perl, along with what you'd need to install CPAN modules. The only way you'd be able to get a smaller footprint is to split it up into packages that declare what each one depends on in the way Fedora/Redhat systems do, and CPAN modules generally assume you have all of it.

Comment: You could try [WSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux) which includes a Perl package (but perhaps greater overhead).

Answer (score 2):

The Perl installed with Strawberry Perl, including all core and vendor modules and a few I installed myself, weighs in at [140 MB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WywVq.png). When you say it uses 500 MB, you're including the build toolchain required to install modules in your total (e.g. `gmake`, `mingw`, etc). This is something added by Strawberry and isn't part of Perl, and isn't required in day-to-day use of Perl.

Similarly, not all of that 140 MB is needed by everyone. A chunk of that is also part of the toolchain required for installing modules (e.g. ExtUtils::MakeMaker, etc).

To get a smaller footprint, you could build your own Perl, or keep only the `perl/` subdir of a SP install, and surgically remove core modules you don't want from that.

For example, you could install SP (along with any modules you want) on a machine with sufficient disk space, then copy over just the `perl/` subdir (minus the modules you want to omit) to the limited machine.

In determining what modules to remove, you could consult any of a number of linux distros that split Perl into a base package and the remainder.

Comment: But of course as the OP states "I may need to install a couple of cpan modules" those build requirements may be needed after all, at least for the installation step.

Comment: @Grinnz, They could install Perl and the module on one machine, then copy over just the files they want to the limited machine where they are needed

Comment: Incorporated into answer.